# zi_lib concurrency example

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Can anyone explain to me how to use zi_lib concurrency with classes?

Comment: Can you be specific about what you are exactly trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the examples in

https://github.com/zlateski/zi_lib/tree/master/zi/concurrency/test

note that you don't have to use zi::run_fn, it's a backwards compatibility thing, you can say:

zi::thread t( zi::bind( function_pointer, arg1, arg2, ... ) );
t.start();
t.join();

same thing with the zi::task_manager::simple or zi::task_manager::deque.

the test have bunch of examples of how to use the synchronization classes/functions